# How do I attach views to nodes?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, entities

I have created a `page` called '**Page1**' of Content type '**Article**' - I have created a  `View1` in `Views` and would like to know how to add that view to my page.

***Does Views replace the needs of the 'add content' button on my admin page?***

Answer (score 4):

Create a view with '**Block**' display. After it is created, make it display on the page you want.

How:

- Go you `sitename/admin/structure/views/add`
- Unchecked create a page option
- Check Create a block
- Give the Block title and select your desired display format
- Click Continue & edit
- Setup your view as per you wish
- Click Save
- Go to `sitename/admin/structure/block`
- Look for your new view block "search for block name you give early while creating the view"
- Click configure
- if you don't want your block title replace your Block title with
- Select in which region you would like to have your view
- Go to end of the page, under Show block on specific pages select "only the listed pages"
- enter the url of page you want your view to be available, for example if your page url is `www.your_site/page1`. Than add page1 in the box.

Please note you can add as many pages as you want and you can also use content type of specify in which node type you want your view to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

You con use [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) (Entity Views Attachment)

> it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are all examples of entity content.

The view should be available as a field in the manage presentation of the entity, it is easy to use if you know how to create views

Comment: I EVA is a good module.
 However it is always good to think it over before enabling a module; too many enabled modules can slow down your site and may be tricky when updating especially on shared servers as their maximum allowed hardware resource usage is much lower than VPS and dedicated servers. Additionally, modules that are poorly maintained and contain bugs can be detrimental to the security and stability of your site.

Comment: True, nice comment ty. :)

Comment: Please notice that EVA attaches a View to ALL entities of type X. That is, if you want to attach a view to all blog posts, fine. If you want to attach view to a single blog post and remain the others untouched, EVA is not for you.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a View "page" or a "block" by default.
If you chose to create a "page" you are right, you don't need to "`add content > page`" as this is done automatically and the page will be at `yoursite.com/path` where "path" is whatever you set in the "Page settings" (top of the middle column) Path field. e.g. "`/page1`" in your example

Answer (score 0):

> Does Views replace the needs of the 'add content' button on my admin page?

No, Views is just a powerful tool to query the contents of your database and to show this contents in lists e.g.
Views can be used e.g. to combine fields from different content types to create comprehensive collections of information and then show them when certain and configurable rules (like arguments and relationships) are met.